# trouble recognizing ball with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create a simple program to detect where the ball is in an image. problem is that I have been getting some weird output from anything i have found online. I have been mainly working from the example provided by adrian at pyimagesearch. link below www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

Here is the [image: original image] and this is the other [image: processed image].

I'm at a loss for what to try. So far, I have tried editing the program to draw all the contours just to see if the balls were being detected at all. I looked at normalizing the image but that did not seem to help any. Any help would be appreciated.

as suggested, i tried a noncolor-based method. Hough Circles ended up working for me. it only sees the ball about 66% of the time but other 33% it just doesn't see anything which is an improvement(because I'm using data this generates, i cant have false positives). below is magic of Hough Circles.

```
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, -1)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (9,9), 2)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, 50, 10)
    if circles is not None:
        # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

        # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
            # corresponding to the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write out a copy of your mask image. I would say that the blanket(?) at the top of the image overlaps your colour range, so it's using that as part of the data for detecting the ball location. That seem to make sense with the size and position of the target.

Comment: https://3gwyrw.dm2302.livefilestore.com/y3mFHCmzEYPnrDf6csfjGY60Ydfl112HOEjCYLKRhHaLqUdHUKiT6gIz8-a06VUiaJOBz3D8V90ZWiLfpw93SXzTQV1dnMOQUZC13RaQ8d4Mw0GZG2xjJ55GZVN2GZRHOEOvn6fgLX2FaTtT47A18m9WyGJQ9z2f7MLxGV6fM61y90?width=637&height=484&cropmode=none

Comment: @ChrisHawley Yes, so you need to adjust your colour range to include the colour of your ball, and exclude the background. Right now it's not matching the ball but it is matching the background.

Comment: any tips on adjusting the color ranges? what i did before was find the extremes in the 2 balls. That range should have included at least the 2 balls.

Comment: i reverted the colors back to what was recommended by adrian. mask now looks like this http://i.imgur.com/lhbswzR.png?1

Comment: Use inRange funtion.: inRange(img,Scalar(0,100,0),Scalar(100,255,100),img);

Comment: The colour based method in the link might not be the most suitable technique for you if you need to match balls of a similar colour to the background.

Comment: @PeterGibson what are some other methods?

Comment: im trying hough circles. i'll post how it goes.

Comment: i can detect circles but not the balls. so...im closer to what i wanted